# Combine sub query with multiple results into one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I achieve the following using only one database query?

```
$query =  "SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `customers`";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$customer_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>";
    echo "<ul>";
        $query2 = "SELECT `sku` FROM `orders` WHERE `email` = '".$row['email']."'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){ 
            echo "<li>".$row2['sku']."</li>";
            echo "<li>".$row2['cost']."</li>";
        }
    echo "</ul>"
}
```

Comment: read about left joins

Comment: read about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` on `email` field for this:

```sql
SELECT c.name, o.sku, o.cost FROM customers c INNER JOIN orders o ON o.email = c.email
```

Don't forget to add MySQL INDEX on `email` field for performance.

But this only select customers which have orders.
If you need to select **all** customers (even which does not have orders) use `LEFT JOIN` instead. In this case `sku` and `cost` fields for users without orders will be `null`.

Use this picture as hint for this. [image]